# java.sql.BatchUpdateException: Field 'myFK' doesn't have a default value

Tags: java, mysql, hibernate

I'm building an application with Hibernate XML mapping with a one to one relationship. My entities are Auto and Targa.

Here's my Java classes definition.

Targa.java

```
public class Targa {

private long id_targa;
private String stato;
private String codice;
...
```

Auto.java

```
public class Auto {

private long id_auto;
private String marca;
private String modello;
private int cilindrata;

private Targa targa;`
...
```

Now, I want to insert an Auto and a Targa in my DB (I'm using MySQL). The SQL tables code is:

```
CREATE TABLE targa (
    id_targa BIGINT(20) NOT NULL,
    stato VARCHAR(50) NOT NULL,
    codice VARCHAR(50) NOT NULL,
    PRIMARY KEY (id_targa)
)

CREATE TABLE auto (
    id_auto BIGINT(20) NOT NULL,
    marca VARCHAR(50) NOT NULL,
    modello VARCHAR(50) NOT NULL,
    cilindrata INT(11) NOT NULL,
    targa BIGINT(20) NOT NULL,
    PRIMARY KEY (id_auto),
    FOREIGN KEY (targa) REFERENCES targa
)
```

So, I create a Java main (I didn't insert the setId property because it's auto_increment):

```
    Targa ta = new Targa();
    ta.setStato("Italia");
    ta.setCodice("FW156WF");
    new TargaDAO().insertTarga(ta);
    Auto au = new Auto();
    au.setMarca("Alfa Romeo");
    au.setModello("Giulia");
    au.setCilindrata(2400);
    au.setTarga(ta);
    new AutoDAO().insertAuto(au);
```

DAO classes use session.saveOrUpdate() method for saving the object in the DB.

When I run the main code, my Targa object is stored in the DB, but when I try to store my Auto object I have the error:

> java.sql.BatchUpdateException: Field 'targa' doesn't have a default value

Can someone help me please ? I don't understand why my column `targa` in my table Auto haven't got any value after my insert.

My mapping files are:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>

<!DOCTYPE hibernate-mapping PUBLIC "-//Hibernate/Hibernate Mapping DTD 3.0//EN"
"http://hibernate.sourceforge.net/hibernate-mapping-3.0.dtd">

<hibernate-mapping>
    <class name="model.Auto" table="auto">

        <id name="id_auto" column="id_auto">
            <generator class="increment"/>
        </id>
        <property name="marca" column="marca"/>
        <property name="modello" column="modello"/>
        <property name="cilindrata" column="cilindrata"/>

        <one-to-one name="targa" class="model.Targa" />
    </class>
</hibernate-mapping>



<?xml version="1.0"?>

<!DOCTYPE hibernate-mapping PUBLIC "-//Hibernate/Hibernate Mapping DTD 3.0//EN"
"http://hibernate.sourceforge.net/hibernate-mapping-3.0.dtd">

<hibernate-mapping>
    <class name="model.Targa" table="targa">

        <id name="id_targa" column="id_targa">
            <generator class="increment"/>
        </id>
        <property name="stato" column="stato"/>
        <property name="codice" column="codice"/>

    </class>
</hibernate-mapping>
```

Comment: Seeing your mapping files would be useful

Comment: Have you specified <generator class="increment"/> in your mapping xml document?

Comment: Thank you @agnul, I've edited my question adding mapping files.

Comment: @Pradeep Yes, I have.

Comment: can you try changing generator class to identity instead of incremental

Comment: I tried to use identity in the auto's mapping, but I had the error: java.sql.SQLException: Field 'id_auto' doesn't have a default value

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have set `au.setTarga(ta);` but ta doesn't have id, as this line

```
new TargaDAO().insertTarga(ta);
```

only persist ta object. you need to retrive persisted id and use it in further queries

eg:

```
em.persist(entity);
System.out.println(entity.getId());
```

Comment: Thank you @Ashish451, but I debugged my main and I saw that the object ta has a correct auto-incremented id after my persist(ta) and after my persist(au). Do I have to retrieve my persisted object the same ?

Comment: I dont know what's written in TargaDAO().insertTarga method. but persistence id will be available inside insertTarga  method only .

Comment: Exactly. I think that my solution is to create a parametric insert query in my AutoDao.insertAuto(au) where I insert the id with au.getTarga().getId_targa(). Is that the right solution, or there is another one using the em.persist(au) method ?

Comment: you can return persisted id from insertTarga() and use it like this Integer persistId = new TargaDAO().insertTarga(ta);